# extract files within an exe file

Tags: wine, kali, kali-linux-tools

I am trying to work through practical malware analysis and there are a series of labs hidden within an exe file.  Since I just need the files to analyse , and would rather not download an entire windows os, is there a way to extract the lab files from within the exe ?

The files in question are located here: [Labs | Running the Gauntlet](https://practicalmalwareanalysis.com/labs/)

As of right now when I try to run wine I get an error that says:

```
Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
```

I have spent the last 4 hours uninstalling, reinstalling, looking at tutorials etc and I'm really frustrated because all I need are the actual files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file [`PracticalMalwareAnalysis-Labs.exe`](https://github.com/mikesiko/PracticalMalwareAnalysis-Labs/blob/master/PracticalMalwareAnalysis-Labs.exe) is self-extractor RAR archive. I don't have an idea why `7z` or Ubuntu's Archive Manager both can't handle it properly. So you need `unrar` tool for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unrar
```

Then you can extract the content of the file by the command:

```
unrar x PracticalMalwareAnalysis-Labs.exe
```

Where ***x*** - Extract files with full path.

Answer (score 12):

The `unrar` solution in the accepted answer is only applicable to some self-extracting .exe files.

If you get

```
Your.exe is not RAR archive
No files to extract
```

then try

```
7z x Your.exe
```

In some cases, this will produce something with `.cab` files in some directory.

To extract the contents of these .cab files, you will need

```
apt install cabextract
```

And since the .cab files may actually contain `.msi` files, you might also want to

```
apt install msitools
```

which provides, among other tools, `msiextract`.

Comment: `7z x aaa.exe` did worked for me after installing p7zip-full and p7zip-rar

Answer (score 2):

This is what resolved the `Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.` message for me:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/wine/gecko && cd /usr/share/wine/gecko
sudo wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi  # the latest version currently available
sudo wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86.msi  # in any case we download both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions
wine iexplore https://google.com  # verify it works
```

Taken from [Dexter Haslem](https://blog.dexterhaslem.com/getting-wine-3-0-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) and updated.

Alternatively, install winetricks and it would manage it for you: `sudo apt install winetricks`.